# I cant install prompt-sync in visual studio

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio-code

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\ibcph> npm install prompt-sync

up to date, audited 215 packages in 3s

9 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

6 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 4 high, 1 critical)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
PS C:\Users\ibcph>

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or VS Code? You have the VS Code tag but your title says Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It is already installed to your current working directory `C:\Users\ibcph`.

Are you trying to install it globally?

```bash
npm install -g prompt-sync
```

Comment: const npmUtils = require("bower-npm-resolver/dist/npm-utils");
const prompt= require('prompt-sync')();

var fname = prompt("Enter your first name: ");
var lname = prompt("Enter your last name: ");

console.log("sadasdas",fname,lname);                                                                                        Im trying this code, its my first day using js

Comment: Caused By: Error: The programmatic API was removed in npm v8.0.0 its showing me this message

Comment: The example I gave you is a shell command, not javascript code. Paste it in a shell such as powershell, cmd, or bash

Comment: I already done that

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2006]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\ibcph>npm install -g prompt-sync

changed 3 packages, and audited 4 packages in 2s

found 0 vulnerabilities

but i cant use it in my visual studio

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'prompt-sync'
Require stack:
- d:\DOWNLOADS\SYSTEM ADMIN\jj.js

Comment: You've installed the package globally. Are you possibly running visual studio as admin but running cmd as your local user?

Comment: Im running it both admin